# Static cast to a class from a limited set of classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to implement a static cast to one of the classes from a set, passed as variadic template parameters:

```
struct Base {
    int tag_value;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base {
    static constexpr int tag = 1;
    Derived1() : Base{tag} {}
    int foo() { return 100; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base {
    static constexpr int tag = 2;
    Derived2() : Base{tag} {}
    int foo() { return 200; }
};

struct Derived3 : public Base {
    static constexpr int tag = 3;
    Derived3() : Base{tag} {}
    int foo() { return 300; }
};

template <class ... Candidates, class Fn>
auto apply_casted(Base & base, Fn fn) {
    //compare base::tag_value with each Candidate::tag
    //static_cast<> base to Candidate if match
    //call fn with base casted to matched Derived
    return fn(/*...*/);
}

int main() {
    Derived2 d2;
    Base & b = d2;
    // should throw error (b.tag_value doesn't match neither Derived1::tag nor Derived3::tag
    auto v1 = apply_casted<Derived1, Derived3>(b, [](auto d) {
        return d.foo();
    });
    // should static_cast b to Derived2 and return foo() (200)
    auto v2 = apply_casted<Derived1, Derived2>(b, [](auto d) {
        return d.foo(); //calls Derived2::foo()
    });
}
```

Well, I hope the code speaks for itself. Code to get started: https://godbolt.org/z/WfaFt- 
I'm looking for implementation of apply_casted. How to iterate Candidates... at compile time is probably the most difficult part.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't seem to be asking anything.

Comment: Next step a visitor for polymorphic types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename Candidate, typename... Candidates, typename Fn>
auto apply_casted(Base& base, Fn&& fn)
{
    if (base.tag_value == Candidate::tag)
    {
        return std::forward<Fn>(fn)(static_cast<Candidate&>(base));
    }

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Candidates) > 0)
    {
        return apply_casted<Candidates...>(base, std::forward<Fn>(fn));
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{"tag_value doesn't match"};
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1fee55db8c6c56a)

---

If the return types can differ, a common one should be specified as a result of `apply_casted`:

```
std::common_type_t<std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Candidate&>
                 , std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Candidates&>...>
```

---

A similar functionality can be achieved with `std::variant`:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template <typename... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

std::variant<Derived1, Derived2, Derived3> v;

v.emplace<Derived2>();

std::visit(overload{ [](Derived2& d) -> int { return d.foo(); },
                     [](auto& d) -> int { throw std::runtime_error{""}; } }, v);
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35c69053ed512b15)

---

For a better performance, you should use a jump table, similar to the below one:

```
template <typename R, typename F, typename V, typename C>
struct invoker
{
    static R invoke(F&& f, V&& v)
    {
        return f(static_cast<C&&>(v));
    }
};

template <typename Candidate, typename... Candidates, typename Fn>
auto apply_casted(Base& base, Fn&& fn)
{    
    using R = std::common_type_t<std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Candidate&>
                               , std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Candidates&>...>;
    using invoker_t = R(*)(Fn&&, Base&);
    invoker_t arr[]{ &invoker<R, Fn, Base&, Candidate&>::invoke
                   , &invoker<R, Fn, Base&, Candidates&>::invoke... };

    return arr[base.tag_value](std::forward<Fn>(fn), base);
}
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ebda92e9a5b0d83)

Comment: Yep, perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to put all the types into a list, so they need not be duplicated everywhere?

Comment: @Deduplicator that's not a question to me

Comment: Your third example is fragile, as the array is indexed by the tag values and assumes the derived template parameters are passed in sorted order by tag value.

Comment: @JonHarper yes, adjusting it to own needs is possible and is left as an excercise

Answer (score 1):

It's too late too play?

You tagged C++17, so you can use template folding (modified following a Frank's suggestion (thanks!))

```
template <class ... Candidates, class Fn>
auto apply_casted(Base & base, Fn fn)
 {
   int ret {-1};

   if ( false == ((Candidates::tag == base.tag_value
                     ? ret = fn(static_cast<Candidates&>(base)), true
                     : false) || ...) )
      ; // throw something

   return ret;
 }
```

Comment: It's a nice demo of fold expressions' power, but I find Piotr's variant much cleaner. (I'm still struggling to parse this in my head)

Comment: @cos - I'm agree. But I find folding funny.

Comment: You could make it much nicer by folding on `||` instead, this way you'd get a nice early out.

Comment: @Frank - Intriguing idea... not sure to understand what do you mean but... now It's a lot more incomprehensible. And I love it. Thanks.

Comment: @cos - sorry but Frank suggested me a folding improvement.

Comment: Also trying to parse this in my head...why are you casting to a pointer and then immediately dereferencing? It's a lovely bit of hackery, though.

Comment: For anyone else trying to parse this, [here's](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/J9mkK9) a sanitized version.

Comment: @JonHarper - no: it's because I'm a old C-programmer and I've the old bad habit to works with pointers; modified without this silliness. Thanks.